# How can I restrict Searches in iBook on my iPad to only the content in my Library?

Tags: search, ibook

I have been using iBook as a songbook so have hundreds of documents. If I search for a keyword because I can't remember the exact song title, I get lists of hits off the web instead of what's in my Library. I used to be able to restrict iBook searches to just my Library. It doesn't help that iBooks no longer integrates new stuff alphabetically either. Or by Recent, or any other remotely logical system I can identify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Books settings, there is a toggle to 'Include Book Store results when searching'. Simply uncheck that toggle.

For Mac, the setting is found in Books>Preferences>Advanced.
On iPad and iPhone, find the Settings App, scroll down to Books, and locate the setting for 'Searching'.